# Simulation: $P(\sqrt{U_{1}}+\sqrt{U_{2}}+\sqrt{U_{3}} \geq 0.8)$ where $U_{1},U_{2}, U_{3}$ be independently standard Uniform distributed

Tags: r, probability, simulation

Let $U_{1},U_{2}, U_{3}$ be independently standard Uniform distributed.
I want to find $P(\sqrt{U_{1}}+\sqrt{U_{2}}+\sqrt{U_{3}} \geq 0.8)$. I would like to solve this problem with simulation:

Hence, I would have proceeded like that using R:

```
set.seed(1447)
stunif_d <- function(N=10000000){
U1 <- runif(N)
U2 <- runif(N)
U3 <- runif(N)
return(sqrt(U1) + sqrt(U2) +sqrt(U3))
}


U <- stunif_d(100000000) 
mean(U >= 0.8)
```

Would this be correct? I have only read theoretical parts about simulation and this is my first practical try. Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: As far as I can see, this is a correct way to go about this. A couple of points regarding your question. You may want to add the word simulation to the title. You should mention that your code is written in R in the body of the question. People typically set seeds to make results reproducible, though not necessary initially. Finally, a minor improvement to the last line might be `sum(U >= 0.8) / length(U)`.

Comment: Compare your result to the PDF $$F(t)=\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{t^6}{90} & 0<t\leq 1 \\
 \frac{1}{90} \left(-2 t^6+45 t^4-120 t^3+135 t^2-72 t+15\right) & 1<t\leq 2 \\
 \frac{1}{90} \left(t^6-45 t^4+120 t^3+135 t^2-648 t+495\right) & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}$$ (for $0 \le t \le 3)$).  Incidentally (@lmo), the last line is most conveniently computed as `mean(U >= 0.8)`. Making only a single reference to the data  `U` enables brief solutions like `mean(stunif_d(1e6)) >= 0.8)`, which work nicely inside larger loops.

Comment: @whuber Ah yes, `mean(U >= 0.8)`, more concise and probably more efficient.

Comment: a minor improvement is to simulate `u=sqrt(matrix(runif(3*N),ncol=3))` and consider `mean(apply(u,1,sum)>=.8`